# Cloning site and $config_directories

Tags: 8, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop

On my local Drupal 8 multisite environment in sites/default/settings.php I have:

```
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config/staging';
$config_directories = array();
```

Because the default direction for the configuration files `sites/default/files` is .gitignored.

Is above correct, or do I have to delete `$config_directories = array();` and put only the first line? How do I have to setup `$config_directories` properly so I can version my Configuration with Git?

Is `$config_directories` the same in both settings.php for the local site and production environment. In other words; is settings.php the same for the local site and production environment, except the database information?

Acquia Dev Desktop also gives:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/griffioenrotterdam-dev.dd/files/config_CBOBWbcJU487p7Gc5z5e4GPzL6pSuEKQytsN6heKUULhL8ziYY7DUJoAbHI-dUxnFEfpzk0W7Q/sync'
```

What about that?

My steps to set this all up where:

- I set up a local Drupal 8 multisite environment using Acquia Dev
  Desktop. All worked fine.
- I have a Git workflow setup
- Now I try to make instances of my local site (clone) for Dev and Prod environments
- With git I pull the Drupal 8 code to my production server
- I adjust settings.php in sites/default/settings.php
- I dumped my local Database using drush
- I import the Database in Database connected to staging (Dev) environment

But when I visit http://staging.griffioenrotterdam.nl/ it doesn’t look good.

**--- Update ---**

```
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config/staging';
```

Is from an old Drupal 8 version.

Now you have to use:

```
$config_directories = array(
    CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => './../config/sync',
);
```

But when I go in admin to Reports > Status report > it says:

> The ./../config/sync folder does not exist. You may need to set the
>   correct directory at the file system settings page or change the
>   current directory's permissions so that it is writable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to do with the config directories.

This doesn't make sense at all, setting a value and deleting it:

```
$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config/staging';
$config_directories = array();
```

The config directory `staging` does not exists anymore, it must be from an old drupal 8 version. You only need `sync`. This can be any directory. The hash is only for security reasons and is not needed outside the public files directory.

And I don't see anything in your workflow that would need a special configuration of the config directory, because you transfer the config in the database.

Comment: Rolled back the latest edit. Please do not change the topic of the question. You can delete it completly if you want.

Comment: so I have a multisite setup. Now for my first site I have in `settings.php`: `$config_directories = array(
 CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => '../config/sync',
);` But I still get that error in status report?

Comment: The error message says, that `../config/sync`does not exist. This is relative to the root of drupal, not to settings.php. If for example you have installed drupal in `/var/www/drupal/`, `../config/` is `/var/www/config/`. You have to create `/sync`inside this directory outside of drupal and make it writable.